# P2P radio broadcasting

Tags: windows, cloud, p2p, internet-radio

I'm looking for a solution to broadcast radio by using a P2P/cloud method, users should also be able to listen to the radio in a webbrowser.

The OS I'm using is Windows XP

Thanks for answers!

Comment: so many buzzwords ...

Answer (score 0):

I use [Subsonic](http://www.subsonic.org/pages/index.jsp) for listening to my music at work / on the road.

Comment: Doesent use P2P what I can see?